# Merging two dovecot Maildirs

Tags: centos6, mail-server, dovecot, maildir

I recently setup mail server using zpanel (with **dovecot** and `Maildir` format) for my domain  and created a user email account with `user@my-domain.com` here.

Here all the emails are stored in following tree in server under `/var/zpanel/vmail/` path

```
my-domain.com
  |--> cur/
  |  ------
  |--> new/
  |  ------
  |--> tmp/
    ------
```

I have all user email from my old server (in same format as above). Where email server for my domain `my-domain.com` was be hosted before.

Problem is, I already have few emails on new server for user and I want to merge both so that it show up all email which I sent from New email server and old one.

Is there any way, I can merge these two maildirs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, But I figured out how we can do it. Just answering my question here so that will be useful for others as well.

We can do it using simple filesystem merge for directories but after that we need to make sure that we give appropriate permission to all files for `vmail` user (user might be specific to **zpanel**).

This is what worked for me . Under `/var/zpanel/vmail/my-domain.com/cur/`:

```
$ sudo chown vmail:mail *
```

Same we need to do for `/new` and `/tmp` directories.

Comment: Could you expound on the merge step itself? Perhaps using `cp -Ri oldMailDir/ newMailDir/`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cp -Rp` to recursively copy folder contents while maintaining ownership and permissions and then delete the old folder.

For example, to merge "INBOX/something" to "INBOX" with dovecot:

```sh
# from the dovecot mail folder
cp -Rp .INBOX.something/* ./
rm -rf .INBOX.something
```